# SQL, comma-delimited entries through many-many table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I've got  typical many-to-many relationship with three tables.

```
---------
--boxes--
---------
id  name
---------
1   Green Box
2   Red Box
3   Yellow Box

----------
--fruits--
----------
id  name
----------
id  name
1   apple
2   orange

--------------
--fruitboxes--
--------------
boxID  fruitID
--------------
1      1
1      2
2      1
2      2
3      1
```

I want to create a view that would result in

```
--------------------------
--------boxes view--------
--------------------------
id  name            fruits
--------------------------
1   Green Box       apple,orange
2   Red Box         apple,orange
3   Yellow Box      apple
```

I'm using a ms SQL. Any ideas how to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select
  b.id,
  b.name,
  stuff((select ','+f.name
         from fruits as f 
           inner join fruitboxes as fb
             on f.id = fb.fruitID
         where fb.boxID = b.id
         for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') as Fruits
from boxes as b
```

Test it here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/101351/concatenate-strings

Fruit ID's instead of name

```
select
  b.id,
  b.name,
  stuff((select ','+cast(fb.fruitID as varchar(10))
         from fruitboxes as fb
         where fb.boxID = b.id
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') as Fruits
from boxes as b
```

Comment: that stack exchange data testing... pretty flippin' cool, I had no idea that was there.

Comment: a quick question on the solution, how can I change it to get fruit IDs instead of Fruit Names?

Comment: It would be a great injustice if this is not made the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has the `group_concat` function. [Here's an article](http://explainextended.com/2010/06/21/group_concat-in-sql-server/) on how to simulate that on SQL server